# How can I fix "Refused to load the stylesheet because it violates the following Content" in Magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, security, magento2.3.5

I've recently upgraded to Magento 2.3.5 and I've been encountering an issue with my Content Security Policy when trying to load a style sheet.

The error (Chrome dev console):
[image: chrome console error]
I've added maxcdn to my csp_whitelist.xml but the error still occurs after setup:upgrade + setup:static-content:deploy + cache flush

My csp_whitelist.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="style-src">
            <values>
                <value id="maxcdn-fontawesome" type="host">maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

I've tried adding https in the hostname, but that didn't make any difference.

I'm curious as to why the violated directives are from different domains as well. `getfirebug.com` is only used for the tinymce editor in my admin backend not on the storefront.

How can I go about removing this error?

Also, could anyone provide me with additional resources for researching this? I've read through [Mozillas CSP guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP), but it's not exactly the same for Magento 2.3.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have this code and it works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="style-src">
            <values>
                <value id="bootstrapCdn" type="host">*.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

Try to clear these folders manually also:

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf pub/static/*
```

Comment: I figured this out and forgot to answer the question. But this solution is absolutely correct!

Answer (score 6):

Magento 2.3.5 p1 added a new module module-csp ( Magento_Csp ) which supports Content Security Policies ( CSP ) headers and provides ways to configure them. The policies can be configured for backend and frontend areas both.

Content Security Policies ( CSP ) has two modes – report-only and restrict. In Magento 2.3.5 p1, the default mode is report-only which is shows the policy violations in the browser's console. You can configure these csp for all third party loaded content as per your custom modules and theme.

I was able to solve all the policy errors for my site by creating a custom module.

app/code/Namespace/Csp/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Namespace_Csp',
    __DIR__
);
```

app/code/Namespace/Csp/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_Csp" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

app/code/Namespace/Csp/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
            <mode>
                <storefront>
                    <report_uri>https://www.example.com/</report_uri>
                </storefront>
                <admin>
                    <report_uri>https://www.example.com/</report_uri>
                </admin>
            </mode>

        </csp>
    </default>
</config>
```

app/code/Namespace/Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                <value id="usercentrics" type="host">*.usercentrics.eu</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="style-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                <value id="usercentrics" type="host">*.usercentrics.eu</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>

            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="img-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="klarna-base" type="host">*.klarna.com</value>
                <value id="googleadservices" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="vimeocdn" type="host">*.vimeocdn.com</value>
                <value id="youtube-img" type="host">*.ytimg.com</value>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self' data:</value>
                <value id="lightemporium" type="host">*.lightemporium.com</value>                
                <value id="usercentrics" type="host">*.usercentrics.eu</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="connect-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="font-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
                <value id="twimg" type="host">*.twimg.com</value>
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>

        <policy id="frame-src">
            <values>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>

        <policy id="form-action">
            <values>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

Add your thirdparty urls/domains to csp_whitelist.xml. All suggestions are most welcome

Comment: Hi. I've tried this solution and it works great. Could you tell me where I would add a policy for the following please? - 

[Report Only] Refused to connect to 'wss://widget-mediator.zopim.com/s/W/ws/P+K0WawtTPyb04Z+/c/1593506456470' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src geostag.cardinalcommerce.com geo.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eaf.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapistag.cardinalcommerce.com centinelapi.cardinalcommerce.com *.sagepay.com *.zdassets.com  *.trustpilot.com *.zendesk.com *.zopim.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

Comment: @Suman Pradhan, I have fixed whitelisted all the domains in the read-only mode next to what step I need to follow.? read-only & restrict mode what are the differences?  could you please advise with a simple example

Comment: @Suman Pradhan if we put restrict mode is there any major issues that will happen? why should we use restrict mode? could you please advise

Comment: @Suman Pradhan, Which value I have to set in "<report_uri>" tag for storefront and admin in the config.xml file?

Comment: @CJNotts - did you get any fix on the same. ?

Comment: Unfortunately No.

Answer (score 0):

You met this issue because the Security Policy was added into Magento version 2.3.5

For detailed information, please check this document: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to use the solution above but it is not working

it is showing:
php bin/magento module:enable Namespace_Csp
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Namespace_Csp',
**DIR**

And yes, I have tried changing "Namespace" to something else and still, not working